# php-cgi.exe is opening up an enormous amount of instances

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I am hosting php 5.2 on IIS 8. Yes, I know that's a horrible idea, but that is reality.

The server runs out of resources after our website is up for a few hours because for some reason php-cgi.exe opens up dozens of times:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? perhaps something wrong with the php.ini file?

Could this be caused by mssql_result not closing the connection?

I followed this nifty tutorial without luck http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi/application

I have actually been able to limit the number of instances, but then all additional requests are getting processed very slowly.

Comment: What does your config look like?

Comment: do you mean the php.ini?

Comment: @cpattersonv1 here it is! http://pastebin.com/Gt4ZMSW0

Comment: @cpattersonv1 is that what you wanted?

Comment: The fastcgi config.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 im sorry i dont know how to get it

Comment: It's either in ApplicationHost.config or in Web.config at the directory level.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 im sorry which directory? although we're running on IIS, this is not a .NET application. i've searched for "config" in the entire website directory structure and wasnt there

Comment: @cpattersonv1 apologies, i'm wrong there are a bunch of them: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/201303291613.png/

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We are having the same issue and the cause of the rampant number of processes occurs when we are hit by a search bot. In our case, the php run, we actually want to be trolled by the bot, but yeah, it stalls IIS every time. I've messed with various values of MaxRequests, Max Instances, PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS but not getting anywhere... php 5.6.1 on 2012svr

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better for you to perform the installation automatically using the tools provided by Microsoft:

1. Download the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
2. Check in Options that you'll use IIS (not IIS Express).
3. Search for "php", select some version and click "Add".
4. Click "Install".